# display the elements from two arrays which do not belong to both the arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I wrote this code to display the elements which only belong in any one array. can we make it more efficient?

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int[] b = {1,20,3,4,15,13,6,7,8,12};

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        int temp = a[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
            if(b[j] == temp){
                b[j] = -1;
                a[i] = -1;
            }
        }
        if(a[i] != -1)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        if(b[i] != -1)
            System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: You try to check the resemblance between the two lists?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "please make this more efficient" is not a legitimate problem description for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for situations when the code does not work. When you want to improve the implementation of a fully working code, use [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm new to this place. I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs with `O(m * n)` time complexity where `m` and `n` are the sizes of the arrays.

There are some ways to improve this if the arrays can be modified:

1. Sort both arrays.
2. Do something similar to the merge operation of merge-sort for the arrays, but with the merge operation being that, if the elements are equal, drop them.

Overall complexity = `O(m * log(m) + n * log (n) + m + n) = O(m * log(m) + n * log(n)) = O(k * log(k))` where `k = max(m, n)`. Note that there is no additional space used in this method, i.e., space complexity is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Definitely.
Currently, you have a `O(m * n)` where `m` is the size of array `a` and `n` is the size of array `b`.

Copy the data from the first array onto a `hashset` (an `O(n)` operation, where `n` is the size of `a`). Then, parse through the second array checking to see if the data is in the `hashset` (an `O(1)` operation).

Consider doing the same for the second array.

Comment: Just a note, this approach adds O(m) or O(n) space complexity.